# Plotting points using symbolic Octave

Tags: octave

I have a symbolic function in Octave (with symbolic package), e.g.:

```
syms x;
syms y;
f = x.^2 + y.^2 - sqrt(12);
```

Which function is used to plot this ? Also, is it possible to plot only specific points, like x,y(2,2) ? Ty !

Answer (score 1):

I don't have that package, so I cannot test, but according to the Internet the basic principle should be:

```
syms x;
syms y;
f = x.^2 + y.^2 - sqrt(12);
x1=-2:.0001:2;
y1=-2:.0001:2;
# plot3(x1, y1, f(x1,y1));  ## apparently errors out
scatter3(x1, y1, subs(f, {x, y}, {x1, y1}));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, throws an error, error: invalid indices: should be integers or boolean,  evaluating argument list element number 3 (at the plot call).

Comment: I can't find consistent info on how to evaluate the function with specific values. Try this: `scatter3(x1, y1, subs(f, {x, y}, {x1,y1}));` instead of the current `plot3` line.

Comment: I managed to plot it by using just "plot" instead of "plot3", ty for your help nevertheless :)